How to use google icons in react
I am being confused, when I read it online, someone says 'use material ui', someone is using react icons. When I see it on stackoverflow, answer for this is very old of about 7-9 years old. I want new answer. Please help me my seniors. I would appreciate your answers.

Do you mean Material UI? Their page has instructions on how to use it in React: https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/ , if you have a specific problem, please include your code in your question.

I meant to use google fonts, not the material ui. Yes, I have heard that google's using is material ui, I don't know about that, srry.

To use Google Icons in a React Project follow the steps:

Include the google icons cdn to your main index.html file
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>


Create a CSS object for the default styling of your icons, be sure to use a global CSS file




.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="material-icons">star</span>



The default icons are filled — You can also use different variations of icons — like : outlined, rounded, sharp and two toned
For each of the above you just need to modify the class from “material-icons” to “material-icons-outlined” , “material-icons-round” , “material-icons-sharp” , “material-icons-two-tone” respectively.

Change the font-size property of the span
